# Do these series converge or diverge? Alternating series test is hard to use here.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have these series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{n^4}{4^n}$$

I think it converges by AST. When n = 8 we have:

$$\frac{8*8*8*8}{4*4*4*4*4*4*4*4}$$

so it seems as if the bottom gets much > the numerator as $n \to \infty$. But how do I show this formally?

Here's another:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

The -1 makes it seems like I can use an alternating series test but if $b=\frac{\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!}$, how do I show that this limit approaches 0 and that it's decreasing (eventually)?

Comment: It is absolutely convergent. Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^4/4^n}{1/2^n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^4}{2^n}=0$, for instance, and use comparison.

Comment: Your second series doesn't have a $(-1)$...

Comment: @kccu thanks for pointing that out, edited.

Comment: The second is absolutely converging as well, incidentally.

Comment: @ClementC. so what if the two limits divided = 0? Limit comparison can't be used unless the number is > 0 right?

Comment: No, a limit of 0 works.

Comment: One series per question please

Comment: @ClementC. the stewart books says the limit comparison test can't be used if the number = 0

Comment: @Jwan23 because said book provides an iff statement. You only want one direction, i.e., the one-sided version. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test (relevant section on the one-sided LCT).

Comment: The first sum is equal to $-\frac{276}{3125}$, the second equals $-1$. Just to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution for both of these series is to use the ratio test to prove that they both converge absolutely.

Applying the ratio test to your first series gives you:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4^n (n+1)^4}{4^{n+1} n^4}= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1+1/n)^4}{4}=\frac{1}{4} \lt 1.$$

Applying the ratio test to the second series gives you:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\pi^{2n+2}(2n)!}{\pi^{2n}(2n+2)!}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\pi^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=0 \lt 1.$$

Thus, both series converge absolutely.